# Nilpotent group and center

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ a nilpotent group. Show that

(i) If $N$ is normal to $G$ and $N \neq 1$, then $N \cap Z(G) \neq 1$

(ii) If $N$ is normal to $G$ with $|N|=p$, where $p$ is a prime number, then $N \le Z(G)$.

$Z(G)=\{z \in G |\ zg=gz \ \forall g \in G \} $

Comment: I think you want to replace "so" by "then".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\rm i)$ Since $G$ is nilpotent, the  upper central series $$1\leqslant Z(G)\leqslant Z^2(G)\leqslant\cdots \leqslant Z^n(G)=G$$ stabilizes at some point. Since $Z^n(G)\cap N=N\neq 1$, there exists a least $i$ in the set of $j$ such that $Z^j(G)\cap N\neq 1$. Since $N$ is normal, $$[Z^i(G)\cap N,G]\leqslant [Z^i(G),G]\cap N\leqslant Z^{i-1}(G)\cap N=1$$ This means $Z^i(G)\cap N$ is central. Since it is also contained in $N$; we have $1\neq Z^i(G)\cap N\leqslant Z(G)\cap N$, as desired.

$(\rm ii)$ You know from $(\rm i)$ that $N\cap Z(G)$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $N$ whose order divides $p$, so it has to be all of $N$. This means that $Z(G)\geqslant N$.

Comment: Why $ [Z^i(G),G]\cap N\leqslant Z^{i-1}(G)\cap N$ ?

Comment: @lechuza By definition of the upper central series, $[Z^i(G),G]\leqslant Z^{i-1}(G)$.

Comment: But the definition is $ Z^i /Z^(i-1) = Z (G/Z^(i-1)) $

Comment: @lechuza For $H$ normal and $K\geqslant H$, $[G,K]\leqslant H$ is equivalent to  $K/H\leqslant Z(G/H)$.