# Given $p$ prime and $H\le S_p$ s.t. $|H| = p$, show if $H\subseteq N\subseteq S_p$ for some nilpotent subgroup $N$, then $H=N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, nilpotent-groups

Problem Statement:

> Given $p$ prime and $H \le S_p$ such that $|H| = p$, show that if $H \leq N \leq S_p$ for some nilpotent subgroup $N$, then $H=N$.

By working with conjugacy classes and orbit-stabilizer theorem, we know that $C_{S_p}(H) = H$. Hence if we can show that $N$ is abelian, then we are done. But I only know that $H$ is a cyclic subgroup, it is normal in $N$ by properties of nilpotent group. Can I extract something from $N/H$ or do I miss some techniques?

Comment: Do you mean $H\le S_p$?

Comment: Do you know any equivalent conditions to a finite group being nilpotent?

Comment: There are a bunch of equivalent conditions (e.g. https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finite_nilpotent_group). But I am only able to use nilpotent to derive normality of $H$

Comment: @Shaun No. $H$ is not assumed to be normal in $S_p$

Comment: But "$H\le S_p$" does not mean, "$H$ is normal in $S_p$"; it means, "$H$ is a subgroup of $S_p$".

Comment: OK, let $H$ be nilpotent and containing $H$. What is $Z(N)$?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven From https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747613/nilpotent-group-and-center, we can conclude that $H = Z(N)$

Comment: But nilpotent does not seem to give me any tools to jump from $Z(N)$ to $N$....

Comment: You have all of the information you need now. You just need to put your old thoughts and your new thoughts together. I cannot give another hint that doesn't tell you the answer.

Comment: Umm...I saw your previous comment $C_N(H) = N$....Let's pretend that I have a brain.....

Comment: Concerning the $+50$ bounty, I am wondering what an "answer from a reputable source" means. Mathematics is generally judged by its level of accuracy rather than by its source. (But perhaps I am being naive.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $H$ is a subgroup of order $p$ in $G=S_p$, and the question already states that $C_G(H)=H$ (it is clear from the conjugacy classes of $S_p$ that $|C_G(H)|=p$).

Let $N$ be any subgroup of $G$ containing $H$. If $N$ is nilpotent then $Z=Z(N)$ is non-trivial. But $H\leq N$, so $Z(N)$ centralizes $H$. Thus $1\neq Z(N)\leq C_G(H)=H$.

Thus $Z(N)=H$ as $H$ has no subgroups other than $1$ and $H$. But then $N\leq C_G(H)=H$, and so $H=N$.

Comment: Why $N<C_G(H)$ ?

Comment: Because $Z(N)=H$.