# If $|H| = p$ s.t. $H<N<S_p$ where $N$ is nilpotent, then $H = N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, nilpotent-groups

> Given $p$ prime and $H \le S_p$ such that $|H| = p$, show that if $H \leq N \leq S_p$ for some nilpotent subgroup $N$, then $H=N$.

The question was [already asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4229979/668308). But I didn't understand the hint. So far, I know that $H$ is normal in $N$ and $H<Z(N)$. From this, how can I conclude $H =N$? I can't see. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: It's better to set a bounty on the existing question than to ask it again.

Comment: The question was asked 8 days ago, so it's not like it's a long dormant question. I also don't see you engaging in that qusestion. You should ask there for help in clarifying the comments, not simply re-ask the question here. Asking for help there might even prompt someone to post a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to note that $C_{S_{p}}(H)=H$ ($H$ has order $p$, so you can assume that (a conjugate of) $(1 2 3\cdots p)$ is a generator; by the way, in general, if $\sigma$ is an $n$-cycle in $S_n$, then $\langle \sigma \rangle$ is the centralizer of $\sigma$ in $S_n$). Now $N$ is nilpotent, so $Z(N) \gt 1$, and we can pick an $x \in Z(N)$, $o(x)=p$. Since $x$ is in the center of $N$ and $H \subseteq N$, we have $x \in C_{S_{p}}(H)$, whence $x \in H$, and this forces $\langle x \rangle = H \subseteq Z(N)$. But then $N$ centralizes $H$, so $N \subseteq C_{S_{p}}(H)=H$ and you are done.